# Taking in user input as a string and converting it to a double to place in a 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

String userInput = scan.nextLine();
String nameArray[] = new String[20];
double gradeArray[][] = new double[20][5];
double avgArray[] = new double[20];
double average;

// iterate through all 20 students
for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
{
    // ask for user input for grade
    System.out.println("Please enter 5 of the student's grade(s): ");
    average = 0;
    nameArray[i] = userInput;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        gradeArray[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(userInput);
        average +=Double.parseDouble(userInput);
        System.out.println("/n");
    }
    avgArray[i] = average;
}
```

I keep running into an error on the line that converts userInput to a double and sets i equal to it within my gradeArray `gradeArray[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(userInput);`.  I'm not sure what the proper method would  be for taking in userInput and then inserting it into the gradeArray as a double.

Comment: You are taking the input only once. Please share what's the type of error you are facing

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have misunderstood how to assign a value from a function. The `scan.nextLine()` is a function that will wait until the user has done his/her input and then pressed "enter". You need to call this every time you expect input from the user. I hope that will solve your issues. Another important thing is that the inputed text needs to be on the right format for a double. So `1.2` will work, but not `1,2`. Good luck!